# Login error after form submission

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

What I want to do is have a form that checks login information, and then, if the information is not right, it would redirect me back to the page where the login form was, but showing a p element that says something like "wrong username/password".

Is there any way I can do this? Or is there any way I can do the login check using only jQuery/ajax?
I have been trying to solve this for the past few hours, but I just could not get it right. Please bear in mind that I am a newbie in the field of web programming so don't be too harsh if there is an obvious answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Credentials should be stored on your server.

Using ajax, on form submit:

1. Make ajax request to php with the users name and password
2. Have php verify authentication
3. If invalid return message to JavaScript
4. javascript can alert user if invalid, else it can change the location appropriately

Comment: How exactly do I send the info(string) back to the JS file? I would have something like this 
        success:function(response_data){ and the response data would be the answer I was looking for. But what exactly is it? a return value from the php file? An 'echo'?

Answer (score 0):

Return from your server a 401 Unauthorized response code (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)

You can return the code using a PHP header directive: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

In your javascript function, add an error callback and update the DOM as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can POST to a login form with ajax.  I'll assume you have some form elements already and just need to post to the login page.  You can create a post request like this:

```
xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); //make a request

xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { //The request is asynchronous, this function will be executed once it completes
  if (xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200) {
    if (xhttp.responseText==0) { //or whatever else your "error" is
      document.getElementById("errorDisplayDiv").innerHTML = "Login failed!"; //show a login error text
    }
    else if (xhttp.responseText==1) { //login page reported a success
      document.location = "usercontent.php"; //redirect to a page for logged in users
    }
  }
}

xhttp.open("POST","login.php",true); //post to your login page
xhttp.send(); //send it
```

So there are a couple of things you need here:

- Username and password form on your login page that will be posted to login.php
- A login.php (or ASP, whatever) that verifies the username and password and records that the client is logged in
- A usercontent.php page that verifies that the user is logged in and displays the proper content, or redirects them to the login page if they aren't.

This was just a quick answer, please comment if you need details on any of this.

Answer (score 0):

Along with what dm03514 said, don't try to authorize users on the client side - anyone can view the source and figure out the credentials. Here's a very simple AJAX implementation using jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/UTCbM/

The 'url' (check_username.php) should contain the logic for processing the username and password. This can be via a database, or something as simple as this (but not recommended):

```
<?php
$users = array(
    'user1' => 'password1',
    'user2' => 'password2'
);

if ($users[$_POST['username']] == $_POST['password']) {
    die(json_encode('login_success.php'));
}
die(json_encode(False));
?>
```

Things to note:

1) Don't store passwords in plaintext. If you're using PHP, check out Bcrypt:
http://phpmaster.com/why-you-should-use-bcrypt-to-hash-stored-passwords/
At the very least, hash and salt your passwords.

2) This jsfiddle doesn't do SSL, which you should strongly consider for logging in to a public site

3) You'll have to add `'dataType':'json'` to the AJAX call (I forgot in the fiddle) if you want to return data as JSON.

4) By evaluating the AJAX response, you can display the appropriate error message in the .login-errors DIV. This is just a quick example.

Finally, if you're doing this on a public site, PLEASE read up on some security best practices in regards to storing/accessing login credentials. If this is beyond what you're looking for, consider reading up on access control via .htpasswd

Again, this is a VERY simple implementation, I would not go live with something like this, but hopefully it will get you started.

Edit: For clarity, the 'error' message returned is because of the 'error' function being called since the AJAX won't work on the fiddle. You'll actually want to code your error messages into the 'success' function, as counter-intuitive as it may seem at first.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer.
Secondly, I think it is my fault I forgot to mention I had the credentials already stored in a database. The password is encrypted with sha1 and md5.

Comment: $('#login').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        'url':'/server_scripts/verify_password.php',
        'method':'POST',
        'data': {
            'id': $('#username').val(),
            'pass': $('#password').val()
        },
        success:function(response_data){
            if(response_data === false){
                $('#error').html('Invalid login');
            }
            else{}
        },
        error: function(e, txt, err){
            $('#error').html(txt);
        }
    });
});
When debugging, I get an error from the jquery.min.js. Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: What error do you get? What version of jQuery are you using? If you're returning JSON, you should add `'dataType' : 'json'`, but even the absence of that isn't causing an error for me. Can you put your code in a jsfiddle, including what verify_password.php is returning?